# How can I share my visualisations in Kibana-4

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

How to share my dashboard with others,in Kibana-4. Also if I want to share only a specific visualization,is it possible in Kibana-4?  Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both,ie you can share the dashboard and also share a specific visualization.

**Case I:** Sharing Dashboard:
To share the dashboard,go to a dashboard and select the button show in the red box 1 in the following fig
[image]

**Case II:** Sharing specific visualization: 
To share a specific visualization,after finishing the visualization,select the button we previously pressed,just like in the fig given below.
[image]